# Encoding and decoding with php and javascript and data attributes validation

Tags: php, javascript, html, validation, encode

Im using data-attributes for sending data from html to javascript

The data attributes come from mysql data so it might have a space in it, so
i get validation errors as it says no space are allowed inside attributes

So the solution i thought if is to encode the value in php so it has no spaces 
and then decode it in javascript once it has been passed on to javascript. Is there a premade function for this?
A failsafe way will be awesome :)

Also is there a way to store values in data-attributes with having space in it and getting it to validate?

Answer (score 2):

spaces in html attributes shouldn't be a problem (just think of the `style` attribute: `style="background-color: #F63;"` has a space in it, but will still work. If the data is sent using ajax however,chances are it gets url encoded (@Brad: `urlencode` is what you meant, I suspect).

since you say the data is coming from an SQL table, chances are the data itself is passed is stored in either an object or an array in php. If so, why not just `json_encode` the data, and in javascript: `JSON.parse(document.getElementById('theId').value);`. This gives you an object in JS, containing all data you have. If only 1 string is required, you can sill use `json_encode` by placing your data in a wrapper array, and encode that...

Do make sure to use **SINGLE** quotes if you string this to html:

```
<?php
    $dbArray = array('this', 'array', 'contains','your','data', 'with spaces');
    $html= '<input type="hidden" id="hiddenArray" value=\''.json_encode($dbArray).'\'/>';
```

If you use single quotes the element will be malformed, since json encoded arrays have double quotes in them:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenArray" value='["this","array","contains","your","data","with spaces"]' />
```

Might not look sexy, but as you can see, double quotes would have set the elements value to `[`...
This doesn't strip spaces, but they won't cause you any problems either.

Answer (score 0):

> Also is there a way to store values in data-attributes with having space in it and getting it to validate?

Just make sure you quote your attribute values.

This is a valid document that passes at the W3C validator.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Data Attributes</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 data-space="This value has a space in it">Data Attributes</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you html encode them in PHP using something like [htmlentities](http://us.php.net/htmlentities) you can then decode them in javascript using [unescape](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp)

```
<?php
$value = htmlentities('hey you'); //hey%20you
```

and then in javascript

```
var value = unescape('hey%20you'); //hey you
```

Comment: The output of `htmlentities('hey you');` is `hey you` not `hey%20you` and [`unescape` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Functions#escape_and_unescape_functions) because it doesn't handle non-ASCII properly.